# Using Mechanize to log into https://kindle.amazon.com/login

Tags: ruby, mechanize, kindle

I am trying to use Mechanize to log into my Kindle account at Amazon.

The login page URL is https://kindle.amazon.com/login

I can manually log into this page without issue but if I try it using the following code it always fails with an error (see screenshot below).

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize_agent                        = Mechanize.new
mechanize_agent.user_agent_alias       = 'Windows Mozilla'

signin_page            = mechanize_agent.get("https://kindle.amazon.com/login")
signin_form            = signin_page.form("signIn")
signin_form.email      = "email@example.com"
signin_form.password   = "password"
post_signin_page       = mechanize_agent.submit(signin_form)
```

This is always the resulting page (again, I'm certain my script is using valid values):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like mechanize is trying to submit the form without the propper action. Try using the *Continue* button, and send the form with that button:

```
# ...
submit_button = signin_form.buttons.find { |b| b.value == "Continue" }
post_signin_page = mechanize_agent.submit signin_form, submit_button
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the results are the same. I really don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: I'll try to debug it again in a few hours. Could you please tell me what version of Mechanize are you using?

Comment: Very much appreciated. From `gem list`: `mechanize (2.7.5, 2.7.4)`